# Installing Eclipse for linux (64 bit)

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, tar, package-management, ubuntu-14.04

So I am trying to download the latest version of eclipse from the [link provided by eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

There is a package available in the software repositories, but it is an old version and I would like the newest one if possible.

I digress, After it downloads, I attempt to extract to a directory, but I get the following error message:
[image: truncated gzip input]

This is when using the archive manager. The package is a .tar.gz, so I tried using the tar command itself to unpack it, but I got a similar error message:

```
...
...
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.debug.ui_3.10.0.v20140604-1637.jar
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.core.jobs.source_3.6.0.v20140424-0053.jar
eclipse/plugins/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.source_4.2.6.v201311072007.jar
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.4.0.v20140606-1558.jar

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I tried removing and re-downloading, but got the same results. Has anyone run into this error in the past and know what I can do? Could I be missing a dependency? How could I check?

Comment: anyone's input here is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the download against the checksums available on the download page to see if it is OK?